# What is the difference between "when" and "before" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> Michael had been living for four years in Italy, **when** he decided to move to America.

This sentence makes no sense to me because "when" is not being used appropriately.

> Michael had been living for four years in Italy, **before** he decided to move to America.

I think the above sentence is better.

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: How is it that *when* is not being used appropriately? Have you checked a dictionary recently for what *when* can mean?

Comment: I have. So what is the sense of the first sentence for you? Had Michael first lived in Italy and then decided to move?

Comment: Exactly: *and then*!  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct.

*When* (as a conjunction) can mean *upon* or *after which* or  *and then*: "We had just fallen asleep when the bell rang." Scroll down to the last *Definition 6* in [this dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/when)

So if you use *upon which*, *after which*, or *and then* in the sentence, you get the meaning of *when*.

Thus:

> Michael had been living for four years in Italy, when he decided to move to America.

These are two separate actions:

Step 1. Michael lived in Italy for four years.
Step 2. *Then* he decided to move to America.

Put together:

> Michael had been living for four years in Italy, *and then* he decided to move to America.

It is just like:

Step 1: We had just fallen asleep.
Step 2: Then the bell rang.

> We had just fallen asleep when (and then) the bell rang.

Note that the past perfect *had fallen asleep* indicates a completed action in the past. The *just* modifies this to mean a completed action that just occurred a short while ago, even just a second ago. But the action was still completed in the past. That is why sometimes it is so rough to be awakened by a bell or an alarm clock after *just* having falling asleep.

Comment: I seem not to grasp it completely though. The decision to move to America didn't take four years. _Firstly_ he lived four years, _then_ he decided to move. It's not that all happened at the very same time.

Comment: I've added a "Two Step Process" idea to my answer. See if that helps. I hope so!

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure about this one? _We had just fallen asleep when (and then) the bell rang._ "When", in this case, does not mean _and then_ but _at the same time_. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, (you're wrong): the falling asleep happens **first**, if only for just a tiny bit of time, even a second, **and then** the bell rang. Because the *had* indicates a completed action in the past.

Comment: If you say: *We fell asleep when the bell was ringing* this indicates concurrent activity.

Comment: I'm glad you do.